# How to display the list of databases and tables where the column exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need a query that scans all tables in all databases on a server and returns if a column exists. I am thinking to use `sp_MSforeachdb` system procedure to scan in a specific database provided.

Comment: query [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: But, I need with DBName.Table

Comment: use it together with sp_MSforeachdb

Comment: May I know what is the key to link sys.tables and sys.databases? In that case, I can get the full name like DBName.Table

Comment: `object_id` or simply `object_name(object_id)` will gives you the table name

Comment: Please don't use sp_MSforeachdb. It's undocumented, unsupported, and downright buggy.

Answer (score 1):

This will search a specific database or all databases if none is specified (it wasn't clear from your question why you'd want to use `sp_MSforeachdb` if you only care about a single database).

```
DECLARE @column   nvarchar(128) = N'column name to search for',
        @database nvarchar(128) = NULL;

CREATE TABLE #results(db sysname, obj nvarchar(300), col nvarchar(128));

DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max), 
        @exec nvarchar(4000), 
        @db   sysname,
        @c    cursor;

SET @sql = N'INSERT #results(db, obj, col)
  SELECT DB_NAME(), s.name + ''.'' + o.name
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  WHERE c.name = @column;';

SET @c = cursor FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
  SELECT QUOTENAME(name) FROM sys.databases
  WHERE state = 0 AND database_id > 4 AND name = COALESCE(@database, name);

OPEN @c;
FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @db;

WHILE @@STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  SET @exec = @db + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
  EXEC @exec @sql, N'@column nvarchar(128)', @column;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @db;
END

SELECT db, obj, col FROM #results;
```

If you are commonly running queries across databases, please [get `sp_ineachdb`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql), which is far more functional (and less buggy!) than the undocumented and unsupported `sp_MSforeachdb`.